# Trying to use Sequelize on Node.js and having problem with create

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to implement the strategy pattern to insert values on PostgreSQL and MongoDB.

[image: error description]

Within my test class, the connection test is working but the create is not:

```
const { equal, deepEqual, ok } = require('assert');
const Context = require('./../db/strategies/base/contextStrategy');
const Postgres = require('./../db/strategies/postgres');

const context = new Context(new Postgres());

const MOCK_HEROI_CADASTRAR = {
    NAME:'New Name Create',
    POWER: 'New Power Create'
};

describe('Postgress CRUD tests', function () {
    this.timeout(Infinity);

    it('Connection', async function (){
        const result = await context.isConnected();
        equal(result, true);
    });

    it('Cadastrar', async function (){
        const result = await context.create(MOCK_HEROI_CADASTRAR);
        console.log('result', result)
        deepEqual(result, MOCK_HEROI_CADASTRAR);
    });
});
```

The following is my PostgreSQL strategy, that strategy is defined as a class implementing an interface with `isConnected`, `create`, `delete`, `read` and `update`:

```
const ICrud = require('./interfaces/interfaceCrud');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

class Postgres extends ICrud{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this._driver = null;
        this._herois = null;
        this._connect();
    }

    _connect(){
        this._driver = new Sequelize(
            'heroes', //database
            'gablemos', //user
            'root', //password
            {
                host:'192.168.99.100', //ip host
                dialect: 'postgres', //tipo de dialeto da base de dados
                quoteIdentifiers: false, //desabilita case sensitive
                operatorsAliases: false //desabilita deprecated
            }
        );
        this.defineModel();
    }

    async defineModel(){
        this._herois = this._driver.define('heroes',{
            //Colunas e definições das colunas
            ID:{
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                required: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            NAME:{
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                required: true,
            },
            POWER:{
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                required: true,
            },
        }, {
            tableName: 'TB_HEROES', //nome da tablea
            freezeTableName: false,
            timestamps: false
        });
    }

    async isConnected(){
        try {
            await this._driver.authenticate();
            return true;
        }catch (error) {
            console.error('Impossible to connect'. error);
            return false;
        }
    }
    async create(item){
        const {dataValues} = await this._herois.create(item);
        return dataValues;
    }
}

module.exports = Postgres;
```

I don't know where I did something wrong, but if I create the MOCK object on the strategy class and use it, it works fine, but when I pass the object as a parameter there is a problem, as seen in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

my context was reciving the parameter, but wasn't using than when a call the create.